# how to get current date time in sql server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to pass sys date to my procedure.
Below is my code  snippet

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
                                           Date date = new Date();
String insertquery="{ call sp_process_job (?,?,?) }";

                    cs = con.prepareCall(insertquery.toString());
                    cs.setString(1,id);
                    cs.setString(2,host);
                    cs.setDate(19,(java.sql.Date) date);
                                          cs.execute();
                          con.commit();
```

My stored Procedure

```
create procedure sp_process_job (@request_id varchar(25),@host varchar(20),@created_on varchar(25)) as

begin

set dateformat mdy
SELECT CAST(@created_on as datetime)
insert into t_job_details(request_id,host,created_on,run_date) 
                values(@request_id,@host,@created_on)

end
```

getting this error

> java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date.

Comment: Just import java.util.*;

Comment: did the same...them I am getting error on " Date date = new Date();" this line

Comment: Not directly related, but note that prefixing your SQL Server SPROCS with sp_ isn't regarded as good practice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238267/what-is-your-naming-convention-for-stored-procedures and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871612/whats-the-best-practice-of-naming-stored-procedure-for-t-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` because the second is a subclass of the first.

You could do:

```
cs.setDate(19, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

And remember that `java.sql.Date` will have everything but the month, day, and year zeroed out.  As the [`java.sql.Date` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) says:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.