# SubSonic3 StoredProcedures.tt & SQLServer.ttinclude

Tags: templates, subsonic, subsonic3

In the template to get the stored procedures I see this line

```
if(spType=="PROCEDURE" &! sp.Name.StartsWith("sp_")){...
```

Why can't the sp's start with sp_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically because that's what system stored procedures start with so you shouldn't use it as a naming convention for your SPs because then the first place SQL looks is in the Master database rather than in your database. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238267/what-is-your-naming-convention-for-stored-procedures/238394#238394) answer goes into detail as to why that's bad

It also stops SubSonic generating code for the system SPs.